# Best practice to create a database schema for Open Auth (Social logins)

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-4, oauth, google-signin

I've done a database schema for user management alongs with their roles and permissions. The problem actually began, when I decide to integrate a multiple "Open Auths" such as Facebook Login, Google Login, etc...

My database table **DB.USERS** looks like this at the moment:

```
id
oauth_id
username
email
password
remember_token
...firstname,lastname,etc...
```

At the moment, problem is, whenever user tries to login via one of the OAuth (Google, Facebook) and there is an email already taken (either by one of the oauths or application's auth library), it triggers an error and cannot proceed.

I wonder what's the best approach to create a database schema for such method ? Anyone who already have an experience with it ?

*I'm using a Laravel 4.2*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an entirely normal situation that the same email address is reported by different social login sources. First of all you need to answer a question - what do you want to do in such cases?

If you trust the social login to report a valid email address, you could simply merge new login source into an existing account.

You could also choose to create separate accounts for each separate login source - in such case you should treat email similarly as a name - without requiring it to be unique. This is problematic if you want to allow email+password logins on your own.

Another questions to consider:

- What happens if email address reported by social login changes for an existing account? What if new email matches another existing account?
- Do you allow users to change email proactively?

Design the process first and then use a suitable DB schema.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying some key elements to achieve what I've expected